How to Set gasLimit in wagmi When Writing to a Contract?
I'm currently working with wagmi to interact with a smart contract, and I need to manually set the gasLimit when calling a write function. However, I'm unsure how to properly include this parameter in my contract interaction. Could someone provide guidance or an example of how to set the gasLimit when using the write method in wagmi?
Here's a snippet of what I've had:
const { writeContractAsync } = useWriteContract();
writeContractAsync({
    address: positionManagerContract,
    abi: POSITION_MANAGER_ABI,
    functionName: "create",
    account: address,
    args: [inputs.tokenOneAddress]
})

